# @Html.DisplayName without loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

not experienced so bear with me.

I would like to use `@Html.DisplayName` (or something similar) for a value in database, it works fine with a foreach loop. But is there a way to show a value from database with the id of the row?

[image: Sql DB Example]

Lets say I have this db on sql and I only want to display CusName of ID 3 with `@Html.DisplayName`, is that possible orare there any alternatives to archieve this?

If possible please supply a working example, as I said im new so it is kinda confusing.

Comment: You need to filter data from database to achieve this. How are you retrieving database objects? Linq?

Comment: @Oscar yup, controller has using System.Linq;

Comment: db.table_name.Find(id)

Comment: Many [LINQ examples here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx).

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq query in view page and filter the id using where clause or you could filter out the value in controller and pass it directly to view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(c => c.ID == 3))
        {
            //use your html display name here
        }
```